# What of the vbs or batch is the best way to convert content of a file in uppercase?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, uppercase

I need to convert all content of a file in uppercase.
It's very simple to do that in VBScript

```
   set fso=createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
   r=Ucase(fso.opentextfile(file2Convert,1).readall)
```

But I want to know if it is more elegant and quick to do that in batch.
Thank you for your understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing an uppercase operation in batch is rather [awkward](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_convertcase.php). You're better off sticking with VBScript for this.